# How to modify and save the txt file? It saved None-extension

Tags: python, tkinter

Previously, I'm poor at English. Forgive me :)

It's my first project. I want this codes would be implemented. But some bug has showing!

Here is my object.
open txt file -> put in listbox -> modify listbox(with button) -> save the listbox and txt file

But after save the txt file, the file extension has nothing! (None)
How can I fix this?

I used open functions ("~~", "w")
It should be saved txt but didn't

```
...

f1= open("To_do_list.txt", 'r')
Todolist = f1.read().split('\n')
listbox = tkinter.Listbox(root, selectmode = 'browse', height=30, width=40)

for line in Todolist:
    listbox.insert(0, line)
listbox.pack(anchor = "w") 

...

def f_save():
    f2 = open("To_do_list", "w")
    for i in listbox.get(0,END):
        f2.write(i+'\n')
    f2.close()
b4 = tkinter.Button(root,text = "Save",width=10,height=5,command=f_save)
b4.place(x=620,y=350)

root.mainloop()
```

.txt file should be saved. But didn't. It saved None-extension.
And it should be open at other trial.

Comment: You read the file as `"To_do_list.txt"` and you saved it explicitly as `"To_do_list"`.

Comment: Also, you should look into using `with` to open files.

Comment: In `f_save()`: `f2 = open("To_do_list.txt", "w")`

Comment: thanks! I hope you have lucky day!

Answer (score 1):

You did not give the your txt file an extension. 
You open it as To_do_list.txt but then attempt to over write it as To_do_list (Without the .txt at the end)

The below code will fix your issue:

```
f1= open("To_do_list.txt", 'r')
Todolist = f1.read().split('\n')
listbox = tkinter.Listbox(root, selectmode = 'browse', height=30, width=40)

for line in Todolist:
    listbox.insert(0, line)
listbox.pack(anchor = "w")
```

...

```
def f_save():
    f2 = open("To_do_list.txt", "w")
    for i in listbox.get(0,END):
        f2.write(i+'\n')
    f2.close()
b4 = tkinter.Button(root,text = "Save",width=10,height=5,command=f_save)
b4.place(x=620,y=350)

root.mainloop()
```